# XPages how to grant access control to send notification email

Tags: xpages

I'm making a public website with contact form, and I want to make notification email to me each time it receiving new message.

In Notes 9 Designer I put Send Mail action on post saved document event. When I test it on Domino Server, the document is saved but the notification mail doesn't arrived. So I check on the server and there's log that Anonymous is restricted to send mail due to policy.

How do I grant access for that particular action so the system can send with server/valid user authentication without erasing that policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `sessionAsSigner` or `sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess` to execute your Code.
This should allow your users to execute your code and send mails as Anonymous.

Its not clear to me how you create your mails so maby you want to check out those Codes from Mark Leusink and Tony McGuckin wich are both excelent ways to send mails with XPages:

[Mark Leusink: SSJS Mail Send.](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=create-html-mails-in-ssjs-using-mime)

If you use MarkLeusink's code you have to edit the `this.send = function()` to use a sessionAsSigner (see comments below code).

[Tony McGuckin:
Java Mail Bean](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter)

Same for Tony McGuckin Code:

```
private Session getCurrentSession() {
    NotesContext nc = NotesContext.getCurrentUnchecked();
    return (null != nc) ? nc.getSessionAsSigner() : null;

}
```

Comment: I'll try the session as signer. BTW I'm not using particular script to send mail because in Notes 9 there's sendMail action in the PostSavedDocument event, goes something like this in source: `<xp:actionGroup>
 <xp:sendMail from="marketing@pr***.com">
  <xp:this.to><![CDATA[#{javascript:InquiryDoc.getItemValueString("InqEmail");}]]></xp:this.to>
  <xp:this.subject><![CDATA[Thank you for contacting us.]]></xp:this.subject>
  <xp:this.bodyHtml><![CDATA[#{javascript:var msg = "To Mr/Mrs/Ms etc"; --omitted--
return msg;}]]></xp:this.bodyHtml>
  </xp:sendMail>
<xp:actionGroup>`

Comment: In the end I'm using Leusink's code. Looks like it working fine :) Thanks